# Is this a bug in string.TrimEnd?

Tags: c#, string

```
"\u4000\f".TrimEnd(new char[0])
```

is equal to `"\u4000"`.

I am passing an empty array, so according to the MSDN documentation nothing should be removed and `"\u4000\f"` should be returned. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

EDIT: Clarified expected behaviour

EDIT: Apparently, this changed in 3.5, I was looking at the 2.0 documentation page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the documentation says "If trimChars is null (Nothing in Visual Basic) or an *empty array*, white-space characters are removed instead. "
So no, not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) is clear:

> Removes all trailing occurrences of a
>   set of characters specified in an
>   array from the current String object.
>
> Return Value Type: System..::.String
>   The string that remains after all
>   occurrences of the characters in the
>   trimChars parameter are removed from
>   the end of the current String object.
>   **If trimChars is null (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic) or an empty array, white-space
>   characters are removed instead.**

So your example is not bug.

Comment: The array is empty. So nothing should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

What behavior would you expect?

If you want to remove trailing NULL characters you should use

```
"\u4000\f".TrimEnd(new char[1])
```